Raster image broken when zoomed out
I used the mosaic to new raster tool to combine 7 .tif images and the tool worked however when I am zoomed out the new image is broken up. When I zoom back in the image has no breaks and looks perfectly fine but I need to include screenshots of my method to include within my dissertation.

